# Could Bardock beat Broly in a fight?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In the *Dragon Ball Z* universe, could Bardock beat Broly in a fight to the death? Assuming that Bardock could go Super Saiyan.

Comment: Please see [this blog post](http://thesffblog.com/2015/06/gorilla-vs-shark-not-so-fast/) for our policy on "vs" questions like this.

Comment: @RandalThor same universe. Second or third result on Google for `Bardock vs Broly` gives a YouTube clip of exactly this. Should be answerable. **Especially** in *Dragonball Z* with its power levels. Voted to reopen.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Yil7fLKs2GA

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are just basing this on power levels alone, **Broly** would win easily.

In *Broly - The Legendary Super Saiyan*, Broly's power level is **1,400,000,000** (when he is legendary Super Saiyan).
For reference, Namek Goku (Frieza Saga) base power is 3,000,000, with his SSJ form being 150,000,000 which is 50x larger (standard Saiyan-to-SSJ multiplier, I believe).

Bardock's only official power level is **"nearly 10,000"** from *Bardock - The Father of Goku*. He went through Zenkai after fighting Dodoria, but to compete with Broly, his Zenkai would have had to increase his power 2800-fold;

```
10,000 (Bardock's power level) x 2,800 (Zenkai) x 50 (SSJ) = 1,400,000,000 (Broly's power level)
```

Again, for reference, on Namek, after Goku's Zenkai, his power increased from 90,000 to 3,000,000, a 33.3x increase.

So even if Bardock manage a 100x Zenkai, his SSJ power level would be max 50,000,000, a small fraction of Broly's immense power.

Answer (score 0):

Only if this was infant Broly with basic fighting skills and Ki control, as when Broly was born he had a power level of 10,000 and what Bardock had was close to that when he fought Frieza's army. This is the only time I can see Bardock defeating Broly without going in to the Xenoverse 2 Bardock.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this that you can [edit] in?